# Eagle library doesn't show up in search after activation

Tags: eaglecad

I am having some problems with adding a component in my schematic. I downloaded it from the official Autodesk homepage but I can't find it in the add list. I activated it and i changed the directory of the library? Any fix or solutions? I could not seem to find any.

[image: panel and dir]
[image: add list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to search for `si5*`.

It is now looking for an exact match.
A wildcard at the end search for *"starting with `si5`"*.

Comment: @CLover32 Consider adding an asterisk before the string as well, and make it a habit. It makes a difference when searching for something like LM555CMM, just go \*555\*.